# Is there a way in React, to have a button copy two values for one button instead of two

Tags: javascript, reactjs

basically before I had two buttons
one button that when you click, it copies the player.general.playerID which is basically a number like 3345554
and another button that when you click, it copies the player.general.eventId which is basically like this 2344343
i just want to have one button
that copies both in react

I am using these two

import { Button} from 'reactstrap'

import copy from 'copy-to-clipboard'

Comment: A clipboard typically only holds one value at a time. When you say you want the button to copy both values, are you envisioning a single value with those two values joined together (e.g. "3345554,2344343")? Or something else entirely? What would you expect to see happen when the user "pastes" after copying these two values? It would also help people answering the question if you can provide the relevant parts of the code you already have (not just the imports).

Comment: Yeah I would like to see something like this pasted when clicking the button. 
3345554,
2344343

Answer (score 0):

A clipboard can generally only have one value. If you plan to use the copied value within your own application, you can however convert an object/array to JSON and copy that instead (and retranslate it to an object/array where it will be pasted).

As an example:

```
import copy from 'copy-to-clipboard';

const valueToClipboard = () => {
    let data = {
        playerId: 13,
        eventId: 55,
    };

    copy(JSON.stringify(data));
};

const clipboardToValue = (clipboardContent) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(clipboardContent);

    // You should validate your data here

    // While you could just return data, I generally return a specific object with the data I want so no unwanted data can be pasted
    return {
        playerId: data.playerId ?? undefined,
        eventId: data.eventId ?? undefined,
    };
};
```

**Edit:** I've just seen your comment that you'd like to save your data as "12345, 12345". In that case, you can just join the two values like this:

```
import copy from 'copy-to-clipboard';
copy(`${playerId}, ${eventId}`);
```

This uses the template strings approach (indicated by the backticks) to put the two variables in a string.